# How the errors of log4php of Apache happen unexpectedly?

Tags: php, apache, log4php

I've encountered inexplicable problem and my website can not be accessed normally,how this problem happened?
My website work smoothly previously,I've restarted my host after this problem,and my website can be accessed normally.

contents of httpd error_log file as the following:

```
[Sun Aug 20 09:20:03 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function is_resource() in /var/www/html/i2active/application/third_party/log4php/appenders/LoggerAppenderFile.php on line 164

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function is_resource() in /var/www/html/i2active/application/third_party/log4php/appenders/LoggerAppenderFile.php on line 164
PHP Warning:  (Registered shutdown functions) Unable to call _shutdown_handler() - function does not exist in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  (Registered shutdown functions) Unable to call _shutdown_handler() - function does not exist in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  (Registered shutdown functions) Unable to call session_write_close() - function does not exist in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  (Registered shutdown functions) Unable to call session_write_close() - function does not exist in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: What changed? Did you look at perhaps package manager logs to see if something updated? Weird error.

Comment: This is a server administration question, not a programming one. Something is broken somewhere in your PHP installation, or perhaps a crashed module due to resources being exhausted.

Comment: Better for serverfault.com? Not clear why can't suggest that under close options for wrong site. Speaking of which I'll go look on meta. To OP - always good to focus on what changed.  - Good luck

Comment: Nothing changed,website works  properly before several minutes,after a while,website can't be accessed,I think it's caused by some lower-layer.It hasn't happened before.

Comment: Sounds like @NickCoons comment was prescient about the resources being exhausted perhaps? Comments still apply.